# Going from small to medium sized websites

Tags: php, frameworks, front-controller

I've been coding websites for a couple of years now, mostly in php and xhtml. I come from the design world, but I'm proud of doing standart compliant websites and great interfaces. Also used Wordpress and loved it. Most of the time there were really simple commercial websites, with no database included, where everything is done from scratch. Every page is parsed through an index?page=xxx and

But I have a few prospects that are larger websites (let's call them 'medium sized websites') where I feel I'm lacking the following:

- How to dispach or render the pages (MVC controller instead of index?page=???)
- Proper page hierarchy and easy breadcrumbs implementation
- Auto generation of navigation menu, or an easy way to maintain them?
- Clean URLs
- Form validation
- Easy database support

I really don't know if I should be looking into php scripts, and refine my skills or get into a CMS (like drupal) or a PHP framework. I found Wordpress very assuring and didn't feel trapped into crazy conventions, but I feel is not the right tool for this. I hate the CMS Page with the big textbox as I am used to code every page by hand my pages are not a title and a textbox. Got the feeling?

My php skills are sort of medium/low still, but I would like to hear some thoughts of what I should learn to take the next step!

Comment: You used Wordpress but didn't feel trapped in crazy conventions?

Comment: I mean It felt natural and didn't limit myself and the project. It just added to what I knew and didn't have to unlearn stuff.

Comment: @Kevin: Someone coming from a front end/designer background, such as Landitus, is likely to find it easy to use; Wordpress caters to begginers well. All that needs to be done to get a theme working is copy and pasting function names into a static html file. If you have a limited experience of php and are not trying to modify/extend the functionality of wordpress then you are unlikely to see it's negatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good framework will teach you exactly what you are hungry to learn. I second Jorge's suggestion of CodeIgniter. I was looking at that a lot until I decided to build one myself. BTW, I LOVE using my homebrew framework, and building it taught me A LOT so don't let anyone discourage you from reinventing the wheel if you really want to know how the wheel works.

Comment: What about Expression Engine. I found a nice explanation where CI is geared towards building web application, while EE is aimed at building websites. Check this out: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/88276/.

Also, this nicely done exposé on Campaign Monitor really helped me get the interaction between developers and designers in the making off a commercial website: http://newism.com.au/blog/post/76/building-campaign-monitor-part-i-expressionengine-weblogs/

Comment: I know the same people are involved in both projects, but I hate Expression Engine with a fury. I occasionally work on projects for a colleague and he always insists on using Expression Engine. Even yesterday I was pulling my hair and wasting hours out trying to make very simple things work as I needed them to. (For example, I wasted 20 minutes googling to discover that you can do next to nothing with custom variables) It's worth playing with to see how they do things, but I will never use it for a real project by choice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend taking a look at [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com).